# Display only properties in Neo4j Tabular format

Tags: neo4j

The Query To create a label in neo4j along with properties is

```
 Unwind $props as properties 
Merge (s:label) on create set s=properties return s.
```

On successful creation we get

```
Identity :
Label :
Properties :{
the actual properties passed
}
```

The desired output should have only properties and not the other values of identity, label

Answer (score 0):

those items Identity and Label found on neo4j desktop at Table column are displayed to identify the object id and node class. If you click on Text column, then you will see the Properties of the node you are returning.

> identity, label are returned on the neo4j desktop visualization only and not when you integrate it on your program

See example below:

[image]